# remove the [''] when printing a list in python

Tags: python

For some reason when I print a list like

```
list = []
list.append("0")
list.append("1")
print(list[0])
```

the output will be `["0"]`

My actual code is a large block of text. Here's a link to the actual code: https://pastebin.com/Z54NfivR

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "the output will be `["0"]`". No, it will not. `list[0]` in this code does not result in a list. Please read [ask] and [mre]. For the problem you are actually asking about, however, that is a common duplicate - please see the link.

Comment: You can cut-and-paste those four lines of code into a Python session.  The result is `0`.  No brackets, no quotes.

Comment: Your actual problem is that you are using `random.choices` with `k=1`, which returns you a list of one item.  If you only want one item, then use `random.choice`, which returns an element instead of a list.  Or, since you want weights, use `random.choices(xxx, weights=yyy, k=1)[0]` to select the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
print(*list)
```

This essentially unpacks your list and its elements are treated as if they were separated by commas in the `print` function.

I used the name `list` because that was included in your example but it is a good practice to avoid using python commands as variable names.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what he wanted.

Comment: It worked Thank you :D took me ages of trying different things and it was so simple lol and also I usually call my lists by some acronym I used the word list because of it makes it easier to understand